# foreach OrderBy conditional

Tags: c#

I like to do an OrderBy if yy = true. If yy = false, I do not want to do the OrderBy. Is there a way to do this within the foreach statement shown below.

If yy = true it would do the following:

```
     foreach (var item in data.OrderBy(a => a.SectSortOrderNo).GroupBy(x => new { x.SectId, x.SectName }))
     {
         ....
     };
```

if yy = false, it would do the following:

```
     foreach (var item in data.GroupBy(x => new { x.SectId, x.SectName }))
     {
         ....
     };
```

I like to combine this in one foreach with a condition.

My other option would be 2 foreach with an if statement.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question could use a lot more detail and clarity.  You're saying when `a` (or `a.SectSortOrderNo`, which doesn't sound like a `bool`?) is `false` you don't want it included in the output, or you do want it included but in the source order?  Is this conditional `OrderBy()` supposed to be applied _after_ the `data.OrderBy().GroupBy()` you already have, or that's what the query you're enumerating is trying to accomplish?  That is, when you say "within" the `foreach` do you mean the body or the `in`?  EDIT: Is `yy` external to `data`?  It seems like dynamically building the query is needed.

Comment: Is it possible to build the LINQ before the `foreach()`, specially with an `ìf()` statement to add the `OrderBy()` part on demand, or should this logic be added to the existing LINQ line inside the `foreach()` statement?

Comment: @Progman, I elaborated further. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually quiet easy:

```
.OrderBy(a => yy ? a.SectSortOrderNo : default)
```

The `.OrderBy()` sorting is stable, which means you can "sort" them by a constant value and get the same order as if you haven't "sorted" them.

Check the following example:

```
IList<int> data = new List<int> { 1, 4, 5, 2, 5, 1, 1, 7};
bool yy = true;
foreach (var v in data.OrderBy(it => yy ? it : default(int))) {
    Console.WriteLine(v);
}
```

This will generate the expected out:

```
1
1
1
2
4
5
5
7
```

By changing the `yy` variable to `false` you will keep the original order:

```
1
4
5
2
5
1
1
7
```

Comment: This is clever, but I suspect `OrderBy()` doesn't (or simply can't) recognize when it's effectively a no-op and will end up having to buffer all of its input, as usual, before it can produce any output.  Compared to your suggestion [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61260237/foreach-orderby-conditional#comment108373867_61260237), when `yy` is `false` this introduces more work for no benefit and would cause buffering for queries that don't otherwise do so (e.g. with a subsequent call to `GroupBy()`, as in this question).

Answer (score 1):

If you find that the overhead of a "null" foreach is too much, you could just conditionally add the `ForEach` to the query:

```
var query = data.AsEnumerable(); //or AsQueryable() if appropriate, just to get the variable type
if(yy)
{
    query = query.OrderBy(a => a.SectSortOrderNo);
}
query = query.GroupBy(x => new { x.SectId, x.SectName });
foreach (var item in query)
{
    ....
};
```